# Trackball user complaining site scrolls too quickly

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have a fairly tall site (a few thousand pixels of scrolling) and with a normal mouse there is no issue.

However, a user with a trackball has complained the site jumps straight from the top to the bottom.

I assume that their trackball is configured to be too sensitive but is there a way of slowing it down on the site or do they just need to configure their device properly?

Comment: to me it seems not possible to change it for the trackball only.

Comment: Can't they use arrows? :D

Comment: anything you adjust would likely annoy mouse users. the needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few. as a web dev, pointers aren't your problem.

Comment: Thanks - that is pretty much what I imagined, that the sensitivity setting on the trackball was at fault but sometimes it pays to see if there is anything I can do instead.